# interrail, can I check availability before buying

Tags: interrail

I understand that on some trains, in particular french TGVs, inter-rail reservations are limited in number.

Is there any way to find out whether interrail reservations are available on a particular train before buying the pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use [this search](https://en.oui.sncf/en/pass/seat-reservation) on SNCF's website, enter your route, date and time and then click the little arrow in the bottom right to open the advanced search. Now check the passenger details, and where it says "No discount card" select your Interrail pass instead. Then click "search" and available options and their prices are shown to you.

Comment: That means that at that time there are still places. It does not guaranty that there are places even a minute later.

Comment: Well, I don't think anybody can guarantee you availability of seats in the future, and that's not what the OP wants anyways.

Comment: True, there is always going to be some risk, BTW when I bought an interrail pass recently Eurostar turned out to be a far bigger problem than the french TGV services. You can check Eurostar interrail availability at https://www.eurostar.com/rw-en/deals/interrail